# About "GUI in C# and code in C++"

Tags: c#, c++, winforms

First of all, until now, all my programming education, has been targeted to console applications, just like everyone who starts learning C and C++. (the 2 languages i know)
 Now, i want to jump to the nice graphical World.

So, I am exploring Windows Forms, i have already got many headaches trying to understand the language that it uses (quite diferent from native C++), but i managed to do a couple of things like using textbox and buttons.

Well, the thing is, i have read in many places that, in order to avoid headaches trying to code winforms in C++, i'd better "Build the GUI in C#, because it's way easier, and the logic, and code in C++". And that is my question, i don't understand that statement, at all. 
 What is that supposed to mean?

Also, it's C# THAT similar to C++,  as to affirm that statement? Cause, if C# was too diferent to C++, i would have to learn the whole C# language

hope you understand my doubt.

PD : Sry about my bad english.

Comment: For the WPF-related suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212245/how-bad-is-the-wpf-learning-curve can help you make a decision, in short it's more steep but it's all worth it... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joan, while it is certainly possible to develop an applications Front End in C# and the logic in C++ I believe it to be a huge waste of effort to do it this way since you only complicate yourself for no real benefit since you can code both things in the same language.

C# has many advantages over C++ and I personally use mostly C#, but I can clearly see many programmers who love C++.

Now going into your question regarding the similarities between C++ and C# the answer is yes and no. Yes in the sense that C#'s syntax is clearly derived from C++. Many things like ifs and for loops are written exactly the same, so if you know how to write an if in C++ you can write it in C#.

The difference (and a critical one that is) lies in the way the languages work. C++ is an strictly compiled language (it goes from C++ code to machine code). C# is an interpreted language (it goes from c# to MSIL and during runtime to machine code). In C# you can't use pointer arithmetic without explicitly allowing, in C++ you can (and will) use pointer arithmetic. C# has garbage collection, C++ does not.

In the end, as I said in the first paragraph you can use both languages to build an application, but it would be highly complicated. My advise to you is to learn a bit of C# and then decide which language you would prefer to build your GUI application. But don't believe even for a second that C++ can't be used to build a front-end since there are a myriad of frameworks for that. One I remember from the top of my head is [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com).

Another option for you is to use "C++/CLI" which is a flavor of C++ which can use the .NET Framework (the same framework C# uses)

EDIT: Thanks Jerry for pointing out that Managed C++ is obsolete and that C++/CLI is the one!

Comment: Managed C++ is basically obsolete, replaced by C++/CLI.

Comment: That's what I meant, but I've never used it, will edit my answer to update the name. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Will my learning curve be steep if i Jump from C++ to C#?
 And, this is a noobish question for sure but, why then, if C# has so many advantages, all c++ programmers don't learn C#?

Comment: The learning curve doesn't have to be steep, as a matter of fact there are many resources in the Internet from where you can learn c#. I personally find the language pretty effective and much easier to work with than C++. Regarding why some C++ programmers don't learn C# there can be many reasons, some might not like it, others might not be able to use it (C# needs the .NET Framework, so if you are working on an ARM processor for example, C++ might be a safer bet), etc.

Answer (score 1):

C# has braces, semicolons, and uses the concept of classes. It has "C derived" syntax, but otherwise is very dissimilar to C++. Java is really the precursor to C#, not C++.

You can build application GUIs using C#, and then use various methods of calling into C++ (such as P/Invoke). Unless you are using lots of existing libraries, or looking for absolute performance, its going to be a headache.

If you are looking for examples of modern Windows GUIs using C++, take a look at the [Hilo example program.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ff686707.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It is not very difficult to switch to a new language. The few keywords you would have to learn are not the issue. What costs most energy if to get used to the new environment and class libraries. That is probably what you mean and it is true, you'll need some time.

Now coming to the split GUI in C# and code in C++, then you'll have to make all bindings and marshalling of parameters if there are buffers and strings for example. I don't think this would make your life any easier. Interfacing with native Dlls can become some pain. However if you use third party dlls and have already a large working codebase you could try to compile the logic code with `/clr` enabled. This generates a DLL that can be used from within .NET directly.

NOTE: WinForms is now out-of-date for new applications, consider using WPF instead. It scales nicely, but the learning curve might be steep for newcomers.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you have native C++ and C++/CLI, the first one is the one you have learned, but the second one is the one you will need to use if you want to combine it with a C# GUI. However, I would suggest you to stay away from C++/CLI because this will cause a lot of confusion if you don't have a solid ground in C++, C# and .NET.

The reason that you can't use the native C++ is because C# is a managed language, so you will either have to find another GUI that fits with C++ or you will have to go C# for everything. For more information about managed see the environment part of [Difference between C++ and C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/gtomar/ComparisionofCandcsharplanguages10242007013053AM/ComparisionofCandcsharplanguages.aspx), the article will also provide you with a good comparison between both.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this aint a direct answer but hope it will help you. Since you stated that, **you are just started and you want C++ combined with GUI**, I suggest you to take a look at [Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/). IMO I found C++ and GUI made easy in `Qt`. Also it's good too.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not a direct response to the question you're asking, I'd first caution that WinForms are already basically a dead-end, so for new code you'd be much better off avoiding them. If you're going to do a GUI in .NET, the currently preferred choice is WPF.

Some people find C# an easier way to do a GUI. It's definitely true that Microsoft provides considerably more in the way of Wizards and such to do it with little or no coding if you use .NET for the job. Other people (especially those with more experience doing so) can produce a GUI in C++ just quickly (or even a little more so) using C++ instead.

Mixing languages like this can work well in relatively large projects where you have completely separate teams of people working on the different parts. For smaller projects where the same people typically work on both parts, the difference in syntax is at just about the worst possible level -- not enough different to really shift gears and think differently, but still enough different that you can't plan on just typing things and having any hope of them compiling. All in all, you're *usually* a lot better off picking one language and sticking to it.